# Shortest path through a space where the obstacles are perfect spheres

Tags: algorithm, 3d

I am looking to find the shortest path between two points in a space where the only obstacles are perfect, non-intersecting spheres.

Finding the shortest path in a 3d space is a relatively computationally hard programming problem, and tends to be formulated in terms of polygons. However, something about a space with only spheres in it seems like it should provide at least some kind of invariant or simplification, but I can't quite identify what it is. Basically, a shortest path is going to look like a sequence of curves around spheres and lines tangent to spheres, rather then a sequence of lines.

Comment: Do the diameters differ ?

Comment: I doubt that sphericity simplifies matters, except that the description of these volumes is simpler.

Comment: Partial thought- you can maybe simplify each sphere to a point, make that a vertex in a graph, edges weighted by distance, and then use bellman-ford starting at the destination. This would provide a lower bound on the distances, for use as a heuristic function for A* in the actual search (with spheres).

Comment: The sphericity definitely simplifies things, polyhedrons, especially irregular ones presnt all kinds of complicated math for path-seeking and choices.  Unfortunately I don't think that spheres simplify it nearly enough to find an optimal/exact solution in a reasonable time for the general case.  There are a number of good heuristics that suggest themselves here though.  In particular a modification of simulated annealig seems like it could do particularly well.